# Office 365 REST Access to OData is disabled

Tags: rest, odata, office365

I've been trying to connect to Office 365 REST Api to fetch user- and room calendar data. I'm able to obtain access tokens and all that, but every time I make a query I get the same response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access to OData is disabled."
    }
}
```

I get the same reply from the oauth playground as well (https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/).

I'm aware that in order to access resource calendar data I need to create a service app with a generated certificate (as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx).

But since I cannot get event the basic information to flow, I guess there's something wrong with the office365 setup?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Antero - Can you please describe your scenario?  Also, for your failed request, please provide sample request and response.  For response, please include all headers as well.